# Why is a xs:string not an instance of an xs:NMTOKEN in XQuery?

Tags: casting, xquery, instanceof

When I try the following `"123" instance of xs:NMTOKEN`, it returns false.
But when I try `"123" instance of xs:string`, it returns true.

It seems to me that the first result is wrong, because a string is castable to an xs:NMTOKEN, right? I.e., I expect `"123" instance of xs:NMTOKEN` to return true.

Is this an error of the implementation I am using?

Answer (score 2):

No, `"123"` is an `xs:string` literal, not one of its sub-types. If you want to obtain an `xs:NMTOKEN` item with value `123` you have to explicitly cast the string:

```
xs:NMTOKEN("123") instance of xs:NMTOKEN
```

returns `true` as expected.